# Windows phone 8.1 save StorageFile as image

Tags: c#, image, file, windows-phone-8.1, save

I want to save StorageFile as image that can be seen in gallery and use later. StorageFile contain image taken by camera or taken from gallery and converted in StorageFile.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to save StorageFile file on phone so that image can be seen in gallery

Comment: You meant save edited image?

Comment: Yes. I want to save edited image to mobile phone, edited image is converted to StorageFile for easier manipulation with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void SaveCroppedImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileAsync("edited.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
           using (IRandomAccessStream stream =await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
           {
               await EncodeWriteableBitmap(WB_CroppedImage, stream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
           }

       }
       private static async Task EncodeWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap bmp, IRandomAccessStream writeStream, Guid encoderId)
       {
           // Copy buffer to pixels
           byte[] pixels;
           using (var stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
           {
               pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
               await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
           }
           // Encode pixels into stream
           var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, writeStream);
           encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
              (uint)bmp.PixelWidth, (uint)bmp.PixelHeight,
              96, 96, pixels);
           await encoder.FlushAsync();
       }
```

Comment: Works great. But when image is taken by camera i get BitmapImage. I m using this method to convert BitmapImage to WriteableBitmap but saved image is whole black. Code: 
public async void CreateWriteableBitmap()
        {
            WriteableBitmap newImg;
            var obj = App.Current as App;
            BitmapImage originalPic = obj.ImageToEdit;
StorageFile file = obj.fileTransfer;
          newImg = new WriteableBitmap(originalPic.PixelWidth, originalPic.PixelHeight);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            { await newImg.SetSourceAsync(stream)}}

Comment: Are you applying any filter or cropping?

Comment: Return Task `public async Task CreateWriteableBitmap(){..}` and add await keyword while calling the method `await CreateWriteableBitmap()`

Answer (score 0):

Save the storagefile with known image extensions (like .jpg or .png) in the public folder, it will show up in the gallery.